# SNI HTTPS Redirection Haproxy

Tags: https, redirect, haproxy

I’m using now haproxy v.1.7 for redirect HTTPS requests, but I have the following problem.

I want to recognize any subdomain that comes from any user for this domain test123.com (as an example) and forwarded to the same URL
In my case, I don’t know the subdomains, in order to put it in the configuration for that, is there any way to put it as a variable or something like that.

Explain the config:

```
...

acl subdomain_is_test req_ssl_sni -i [any subdomain that comes to him from this domain].test123.com

use_backend bknd_snipt_test if subdomain_is_test

backend bknd_snipt_test
      mode tcp
      server snipt-test [any subdomain that comes to him from this domain].test123.com:443
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions in your acl.

```
acl valid_domains hdr(host) -m reg -i ^[^\.]+\.example\.org$
```

See [HAProxy Docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#7.1.4) for more information.